# Python error in calling the function

Tags: python-2.7

I have a class have these two methods:

```
  def whatIsYourName(self):
        print 'my name is class A'
    def whatIsYourName(self, name):
        print 'my name is {0}, I am class A'.format(name)
```

I can call the second one. But when I call the first one like this:

```
x = myClass()
x.whatIsYourName()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: whatIsYourName() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**I am using python 2.7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not support method overloading. The method defined in the end will overwrite all the methods with same name defined earlier.

However, You can make use of Multi Method pattern to achieve this. Please refer [Guido's post](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to overload a method. `whatIsYourName(self)` is being over-ridden by `whatIsYourName(sel,name)`. If you are a C++/Java programmer, this might sound normal to you, but unfortunately it's not the same with Python. If you want to display a name, try defining it in a constructor and have it printed.